# ggplot2: add labels to plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, customization, errorbar

I need help customizing my plot. Can someone help me in adding labels to this plot.
[image]

I would like the add vertical labels next to each error bar with the Location name, as well as the cohort for 2021 (see location names in image, although it has its own column in the data frame). I would also like to add a label for year at the bottom of each group.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
#### METABOLITE DATA ####

TRIG_rawdata = read.csv("C:\\Users\\o_tru\\OneDrive\\ARP\\Metabolites\\SUSC metabolites_TrueTRIG_2005-2006_2021.csv")

## Create error plot ##

# Combine age and sex to create single ("COHORT") factor (HYF = Hatch Year Female, HYM = Hatch Year Male, AHYF = AFTER Hatch Year Female, AHYM = AFTER Hatch Year Male)
library(dplyr)
SUSC_TRIG = mutate(TRIG_rawdata, Cohort = case_when(Age == "HY" & Sex == "F"  ~ "HYF", Age == "HY" & Sex == "M"  ~ "HYM", Age == "AHY" & Sex == "F"  ~ "AHYF", 
                                                    Age == "AHY" & Sex == "M"  ~ "AHYM"))

# Combine Age, Habitat type , and Cohort

SUSC_TRIG_subset = mutate(SUSC_TRIG, Habitat_Year_Cohort = case_when(Year == "2005" & Habitat.Type == "Seagrass (hard-bottom)" & Cohort == "AHYM" ~ "Seagrass (hard-bottom) 2005", 
                                                                              Year == "2005" & Habitat.Type == "Seagrass (soft-bottom)" & Cohort == "AHYM" ~ "Seagrass (soft-bottom) 2005",
                                                                              Year == "2005" & Habitat.Type == "Mussel (mixed substrate)" & Cohort == "AHYM" ~ "Mussel (mixed substrate) 2005", 
                                                                              Year == "2006" & Habitat.Type == "Seagrass (hard-bottom)" & Cohort == "AHYM" ~ "Seagrass (hard-bottom) 2006",
                                                                              Year == "2006" & Habitat.Type == "Seagrass (soft-bottom)" & Cohort == "AHYM" ~ "Seagrass (soft-bottom) 2006", 
                                                                              Year == "2006" & Habitat.Type == "Mussel (mixed substrate)" & Cohort == "AHYM" ~ "Mussel (mixed substrate) 2006", 
                                                                              Year == "2021" & Habitat.Type == "Mussel (mixed substrate)" & Cohort == "AHYF" ~ "After Hatch Year Female 2021", 
                                                                              Year == "2021" & Habitat.Type == "Mussel (mixed substrate)" & Cohort == "AHYM" ~ "After Hatch Year Male 2021", 
                                                                              Year == "2021" & Habitat.Type == "Mussel (mixed substrate)" & Cohort == "HYF" ~ "Hatch Year Female 2021", 
                                                                              Year == "2021" & Habitat.Type == "Mussel (mixed substrate)" & Cohort == "HYM" ~ "Hatch Year Male 2021"))


 
# Error plot of TRIG values (GGPLOT2) -------------------------------------
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# reorder x-axis
SUSC_TRIG_subset$Habitat_Year_Cohort <-factor(SUSC_TRIG_subset$Habitat_Year_Cohort, levels=c("Seagrass (hard-bottom) 2005", "Seagrass (soft-bottom) 2005", "Mussel (mixed substrate) 2005", 
                                                                                             "After Hatch Year Male 2021", "After Hatch Year Female 2021", 
                                                                                             "Hatch Year Male 2021", "Hatch Year Female 2021",
                                                                                             "Seagrass (hard-bottom) 2006", "Seagrass (soft-bottom) 2006", "Mussel (mixed substrate) 2006")) #reorder x-axis

# dummy data
SUSC_TRIG_subset = data.frame(
  Habitat_Year_Cohort = c("Seagrass (hard-bottom) 2005","Seagrass (soft-bottom) 2005", "Mussel (mixed substrate) 2005",
    "After Hatch Year Male 2021", "After Hatch Year Female 2021", "Hatch Year Male 2021", "Hatch Year Female 2021", 
    "Seagrass (hard-bottom) 2006","Seagrass (soft-bottom) 2006", "Mussel (mixed substrate) 2006"),
  Month = c("Dec", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar"),
  True.TRIG = rnorm(30, sd = 0.5) + 1
) %>%
  mutate(
    Habitat_Year_Cohort = factor(Habitat_Year_Cohort, levels = unique(Habitat_Year_Cohort))
  )

# ggplot2
SUSC_TRIG_subset %>%
  group_by(
    Habitat_Year_Cohort
  ) %>%
  summarise( # for Mean-SD error bar
    ymin = mean(True.TRIG) - sd(True.TRIG),
    ymax = mean(True.TRIG) + sd(True.TRIG),
    TRIG = mean(True.TRIG),
    Month = first(Month)
  ) %>%
  mutate( # create group for color
    group = case_when(
      grepl("Seagrass \\(hard-bottom\\)", Habitat_Year_Cohort) ~ "Seagrass (hard-bottom)",
      grepl("Seagrass \\(soft-bottom\\)", Habitat_Year_Cohort) ~ "Seagrass (soft-bottom)",
      TRUE ~ "Mussel"
  )) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Month, TRIG, 
             group = Habitat_Year_Cohort, # group for dodge position
             color = group)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), 
                position = position_dodge(0.6), 
                width = 0.2) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.6), 
             size = 4) + # size of point
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Seagrass (hard-bottom)" = "#FFFFFF", 
                                "Seagrass (soft-bottom)" = "#999999", 
                                "Mussel" = "#000000")) +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(), # remove legend title
        legend.position="top") +
  labs(x = NULL) # remove x label
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Could you provide the content of the CSV file? It would be helpful

Comment: Hi Emmanuel, I don't think I can upload csv files? but I did include some dummy data.